# Flyway Oracle Deployment

Tags: deployment, oracle11g, version-control, automation, flyway

I just started working on a new project. We are building a new application from scratch. Team started with a brand new schema. I wanted to automate the database build process, so I started looking for the options. Flyway seems to be a good one. I have been playing around a bit and found some limitations of the tool. Perhaps, someone will be able to help.

We have the following directory structure for SQL files: 
SQL
  -- DDL
  -- DML
  -- PACKAGES

We are doing agile development, so file names are based on the sprint number. The file naming convention we are using is:
Sprint#_script#_userstory#_description

For example: 
S1_01_US123_CreateNewTable.sql
S1_02_US123_AddConstraint.sql

Next sprint:
S2_01_US456_AddColumn.sql

And so on...

I setup the JDBC parameter and I am able to connect. I tested basic things like: clean, repair, info and migrate with couple of test scripts and that worked like a charm. I started to run into issues when I tried deploying all the scripts. Issues like:
- It didn't like single underscore.
- It didn't like the file names starting with S1_01_*, rest of the file name is different and they are in different folders.

I have the following questions:

- Can I build using Flyway without having to rename the files?
- How can I get it to deploy in this order:

  - DDLs
  - DMLs
  - Packages (everytime I deploy). And we have a separate header and body files, so deploy header first as well.
- Can I change the structure of schema_version table?
- Can I do selective clean? Like flag some of the objects to not to be dropped?

My main concern is running DDLs before everything else. If I can accomplish that, then I can start using Flyway and learn as I go.

Thanks in advance.

Harbinder

- 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I build using Flyway without having to rename the files?

Maybe. Experiment with the `flyway.sqlMigrationSeparator` property. Try "_US" which will break after the script number. You'll also need to set `flyway.sqlMigrationPrefix=S`.

> How can I get it to deploy in this order: DDLs, DMLs, Packages (everytime I deploy). And we have a separate header and body files, so deploy header first as well.

Specify multiple locations (separated with comma) and ensure the version numbering ordering makes sense as if these files were all in the same directory. If running from the command line, turn on debug with `-X` to see how flyway collects the migrations.

Additionally, if possible, you should consider renaming your packages as a Repeatable migration (default:R) so that you just need to change the contents of the file for flyway to pick it up.

> Can I change the structure of schema_version table?

No. This is managed by flyway.

> Can I do selective clean? Like flag some of the objects to not to be dropped?

No. In this situation it might be best to set flyway.cleanDisabled=true to stop accidental mistakes. There are callbacks before and after clean if you wish to do extra cleaning but I don't think you can restrict clean itself without delving into the code.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks much! I have been doing exactly what you suggested.

Comment: Is there any callback sql afterFailiedMigration or something?

Comment: @HSingh85 there isn't a [callback](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks) only for failed migrations. You would need to manage it in the `afterMigrate` or `afterEachMigrate`. Also, please accept the answer if it has helped.

Comment: But afterMigrate or afterEachMigrate does not get invoked in case of failure.

Comment: @HSingh85; thanks for clarifying. Looks like this feature has been requested [1392](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1392) and [1709](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1709)